# Rewrite mod htaccess php hide php file and var name, only see var value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite this :

http://abc.com/x.php?var=123

to:

http://abc.com/123

Please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ x.php?var=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And you can accept only numbers with:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ x.php?var=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

With sub request. You can change `x` char starting RewriteRule`^x/`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^x/([0-9]+)$ x.php?var=$1 [L]
```

Now you can request like: `abc.com/x/963`

Alternative:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^x/([0-9]+)$ x.php?var=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This will return 'x.php' as var value !

Comment: But why it affect to another php file ? I just want x.php

Comment: Access another file return filename as var value !

Comment: What exactly do you want? What mean var value?

Comment: variable value is '123'

Comment: `([0-9]+)` is mean only numbers. What is the problem?

Comment: This htaccess make me can not use another php file in same directory

Comment: You requesting base url. It seems a little complex. Hmm..

Comment: Now all another .php file are request x.php :(

Comment: If you request like `http://abc.com/x/123`, all problems clear

Comment: Ok, but how to do it ? other files are still unavailable to  use

Comment: abc.com/x/963 returned 404 not found error

Comment: other files are usable now !

Comment: Updated, try with `[L]`

Comment: I tried and it works. Paste to question your full htaccess

Comment: `RewriteEngine on`
`RewriteRule ^x/(.*)$ x.php?var=$1 [L]`

Comment: Break line after `RewriteEngine on`. It should be two lines. And all .htaccess is this?

Comment: Yes, they are 2 line, my mistake. Yes whole htaccess

Comment: It works for me.. Added alternative code

Comment: It was works before we put the `x` char at first?

Comment: Update delay for over 10 sec due to remote connection , sorry !

Comment: @Đức Works? Or you gave up?

Comment: No no, work, check it out !!!

Comment: http://shorturl.rapeit.net/go/d263740348f5ed87a786b5608a5ff1da

Comment: I'm making a simple standalone url shortener, goo.gl limits a heap !

Comment: I Use http://www.getrank.org/tools/keyword-extractor/ everyweek to harvest keyword for Scrapebox, nice tool !

Comment: I was very surprised. And im working on new script that contains all tools for webmaster. Soon possible ;)